# check if file is a valid pgp encrypted file

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I need to check to see if a file is a valid pgp encrypted file or not. Some pgp files that we get have an extension of pgp and some dont. I need to check to see which of the files are pgp encrypted files and which are not. Please let me know if there is a way to tell.

Comment: Look into `libmagic` and the `file` command which uses it.

Answer (score 4):

The only certain way is to attempt decrypting the file (e.g. with gpg) and interpret the error output. Unless you limit input to ascii-armored files, in that case you can check for the armor.

Answer (score 3):

The [python-gpgme library](https://launchpad.net/pygpgme) is a Pythonic wrapper for GPGME, the library allowing programmatic GnuPG access.

If you have some files that may or may not be GnuPG encrypted:

```
$ head --bytes=1024k < /dev/urandom > lorem
$ head --bytes=1024k < /dev/urandom | gpg --encrypt --recipient DEADBEEF > ipsum
```

With the `gpgme` module you can attempt to decrypt the files:

```python
import gpgme
import io

context = gpgme.Context()
for infile_path in ['lorem', 'ipsum']:
    with open(infile_path, 'rb') as infile:
        outfile = io.BytesIO()
        try:
            context.decrypt(infile, outfile)
        except gpgme.GpgmeError as exc:
            if exc.code == gpgme.ERR_NO_DATA:
                print(
                    "Not a GnuPG-encrypted file: ‘{path}’ ({error})".format(
                        path=infile.name, error=exc.strerror))
            else:
                print(
                    "Error decrypting file: ‘{path}’ ({error})".format(
                        path=infile.name, error=exc.strerror))
        else:
            print("Successfully decrypted: ‘{path}’".format(
                path=infile.name))
```

That lets you handle three conditions:

- The `gpgme.Context.decrypt` method fails, and the error code is `gpgme.ERR_NO_DATA`. This means the data stream was not recognised as GnuPG-encrypted data.
- The `gpgme.Context.decrypt` method fails for some other reason. You'll need to decide which other errors you care about here.
- The `gpgme.Context.decrypt` method succeeds.  Obviously, the file is a correctly-encrypted file.

Comment: Running given script with Python 2.7.13 I get `NameError: name 'context' is not defined`.